# How to run g++-6 on debian 10, need to compile older buildroot system (Cross compiling)

Tags: c++, g++, debian, cross-platform, buildroot

How to run g++-6 on debian 10, need to compile older buildroot files.(NCurves(host-ncurses-5.9) is crashing)

I have tried to patch the files in the buildroot but it like walking into a swamp.

Fixing one problem to find the next problem.
Tried compiling 6.3 compiler from source but this is crashing with the latest gcc-8 compiler.
Any suggestions? (I always assumed that older compilers should compile with newer compilers)

My other options are:
* Running virtual machine (VM or docker) with Debian Jessie
* Compile an older compiler with a docker GCC compiler.(No idea if this works)
* maybe turn off the compiling of the local files in buildroot? (Could not find any info on this)

Answer (score 1):

There is a gcc-6 package available in Debian. So you just need to `sudo apt install gcc-6`. [link](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=gcc-6)

No reason to compile gcc from source unless you need a very specific version, but even then Docker is the far easier solution since gcc has an official repo on Docker Hub. I'd also double check that you have the proper ncurses dev library installed.

The overall best solution is to containerize the correct build environment (compiler, libraries, etc.), though. It ensures you'll always be able to build the product, especially if a re-factor is not viable.

Comment: ... debian buster repositories seem no longer to have gcc-6 package available ... so maybe building gcc from source is necessary these days ... i had to try gcc-6 in debian buster with raspberry pi to try to compile an older version of openFrameworks, but so far failed so gave up : ) ... using container ( or maybe nspawn ) ... might be a good way to go

Comment: ... another page discusses : [Unable to locate package gcc-6 on Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/566500/unable-to-locate-package-gcc-6-on-debian)

Comment: My answer covers this already by discussing containers. Still no reason to compile from source.

Comment: it was only a comment, not an answer .. i, maybe mistakenly, believed my comment and link could be slightly relevant and possibly slightly helpful to someone, seeing as this page has not much activity or other text input .... so not intended to criticise or attack!! your anser was slightly helpful also!! ... and mentioning nspawn ... and only i said 'maybe' compile from source !!

Comment: ... and the question is concerning debian 10 ...so could use repository 'oldstable' to get gcc-6 ... perhaps